# What is wrong with my code? The output doesn't show

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming so I'm stuck with this code..I'm trying to implement a linked list and apply the functions mentioned in comments.
When I debug the program, it shows no errors, but when I run the code it says "Console application stopped working.."
I don't know what's wrong here. Why does it not work?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

/*• InsertNodeAtFront()
•   InsertNodeAtBack()
•   PrintList()
*/

class list {
 struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
}; 
node *head; 
node *current;
public:
    list() {
        head = NULL;
        current = NULL;
    }

    void InsrtAtFront(int n) {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            temp = head;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
}
    void InsrtAtBack(int a) {
        node *temp1 = new node;
        temp1->data = a;
        temp1->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            temp1 = head;
        }
        else {
            current = head;
            while (current->next!=NULL){
                current = current->next;
            }
            current = temp1;
        }
    }
    void print() {
        current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            cout << current->data;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};

void main() {
    list obj1, obj2, obj3;
    obj3.print();
    obj1.InsrtAtFront(5);
    obj1.InsrtAtFront(7);
    obj1.InsrtAtFront(9);
    obj3.print();
    obj2.InsrtAtBack(2);
    obj2.InsrtAtBack(4);
    obj2.InsrtAtBack(6);
    obj3.print();
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, do you have that comment stored on the side, or perhaps some browser macro to plug it right in? You are able to add it super fast :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Here you go: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-snippet/nfhllbdppejecjnhnjjagjhpcbjhkcpf?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: @StoryTeller :) Make your life easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
list() {
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
} 
void print() {
    current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        cout << current->data;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
//in main
list obj1, obj2, obj3;
obj3.print();
```

So. You inited head with NULL and then trying to use while on current that is head and that is null..